# UWP C# Cleaning up secondary page

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm opening a secondary UWP page, and which is essentially detail of an item clicked on the main page.  However, when closing the secondary page, the memory is not returned, nor do I see a close event I can utilize in order to attempt to dispose or GC.  Each time opening a secondary page may takes up to 15MB depending on the level of detail.  If I open/close 20 pages, I've wasted 250MB that I can't seem to reclaim.

The code to open the new page is:

```
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {

            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(Disk), null);                
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

There is nothing in my main page's frame.BackStack.  Is there any way to use the "newViewId" to find the frame and remove or destroy it to reclaim the memory?

Comment: You don't need to create new Frame. Just call navigate on Frame object you already have instantiated. Check out examples on [Frame Class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame)

Comment: I don't want to navigate away from the initial view, which is why I'm not running `Frame.Navigate()`.  I want the secondary pop-up window, which is working as great, except for the memory not being reclaimed.

Comment: Why you are not using [Popup Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) then? Please, submit also code that is closing/returning back to initial view.

Comment: I had thought about a popup, but it has a few shortcomings 1) It overlays the current screen and I can't move it to the side or to another monitor.    2) I may want to get information from two or more items on my ListView, and this way I can receive multiple independent windows. 3) My main window will constantly receive live information updating the ListView which we need to see.  I don't have any code on the closing of the secondary view/window.  I just click the "X" button on the top right corner.  This is part of the problem, there is no close event on the secondary pages.

Comment: Didi you followed [Multiple Views Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Views-Sample-2582fcf3/view/SourceCode)?

Comment: Have you tried to `GC` manually?

Comment: Nicko, yes I've tried GC, doesn't seem to help.  Cloud, That sample apparently only works with VS2013, I was trying to follow the msdn guidelines, but doesn't deal with closing the secondary page or cleaning it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views

Comment: I did find this, [https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews) that seems to have a way to cleanup objects.  I'll try and extract what I need from the sample and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10SDK had the answer in their Multiple Views example:  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews

A few edits will be necessary to get everything working appropriately within your namespaces etc.

1) Add to the App.cs

```
    partial void Construct();

    // Hook into OnLaunched here.
    partial void OverrideOnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args, ref bool handled);

    // Hook into InitializeMainPage here.
    partial void InitializeRootFrame(Frame frame);
```

2) Implement the `SampleConfigurations.cs` class file from the SDK and update to your namespace.  You only need to implement the `class App`  and it essentially adds a few functions and objects to `class App` essentially it creates a `dispatcher` and a collection of `SecondaryViews` for use later.

3) Implement the `ViewLifetimeControls.cs` as is which will control your secondary views (its namespace is `SecondaryViewsHelpers` and implements the events and functions necessary for keeping track of the secondary views and destroying the objects when closing.

4) Add using `using SecondaryViewsHelpers;` to the page that will be launching the secondary view.  To launch the secondary view use the below code:

```
        ViewLifetimeControl viewControl = null;
        await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // This object is used to keep track of the views and important
            // details about the contents of those views across threads
            // In your app, you would probably want to track information
            // like the open document or page inside that window
            viewControl = ViewLifetimeControl.CreateForCurrentView();
            viewControl.Title = "";
            // Increment the ref count because we just created the view and we have a reference to it                
            viewControl.StartViewInUse();

            var frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage), viewControl);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            // This is a change from 8.1: In order for the view to be displayed later it needs to be activated.
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = viewControl.Title;
            ((App)App.Current).SecondaryViews.Add(viewControl);
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(viewControl.Id, ViewSizePreference.Default, ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id, ViewSizePreference.Default);
```

5) On the secondary page, you'll need to reference, `using SecondaryViewsHelpers;` and declare the below objects/variables:

```
    ViewLifetimeControl thisViewControl;
    int mainViewId;
    CoreDispatcher mainDispatcher;
```

Add the below code to the secondary page to assign the objects above and register the event

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            thisViewControl = (ViewLifetimeControl)e.Parameter;
            mainViewId = ((App)App.Current).MainViewId;
            mainDispatcher = ((App)App.Current).MainDispatcher;
            // When this view is finally released, clean up state
            thisViewControl.Released += ViewLifetimeControl_Released;
        }

        private async void ViewLifetimeControl_Released(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((ViewLifetimeControl)sender).Released -= ViewLifetimeControl_Released;
            // The ViewLifetimeControl object is bound to UI elements on the main thread
            // So, the object must be removed from that thread
            await mainDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ((App)App.Current).SecondaryViews.Remove(thisViewControl);
            });

            // The released event is fired on the thread of the window
            // it pertains to.
            //
            // It's important to make sure no work is scheduled on this thread
            // after it starts to close (no data binding changes, no changes to
            // XAML, creating new objects in destructors, etc.) since
            // that will throw exceptions
            Window.Current.Close();
        }
```

Now when closing the secondary windows, I can see the being given back.  My only concern is that this takes over the parameters which I would otherwise send data to the newly created view.  I'll have to find a workaround to pass info to the secondary page - maybe using the title temporarily.